# typo3 404 error only in IE and Firefox on tt_news detail-view (Chrome/Edge/Opera/Safari working)

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, typo3, http-status-code-404, realurl

i have a curious problem.
The detail-view of our tt_news plugin generates a 404 error in IE and Firefox but only in those browsers.
We do have realurl installed but the error persists even without it.

I know our customer has a Windows IIS Server and we had to create some web.config files for the error-handling to work via realurl but i don't know where to look anymore.

Can anyone help pointing me in the right direction?

Comment: I’d start by checking what about the requests these browsers make is different from the ones others make ...

Comment: Fireforx:

Host 
"www.example.com"
User-Agent 
"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0;… Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0"
Accept 
"text/html,application/xhtml+x…lication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
Accept-Language 
"de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3"
Accept-Encoding 
"gzip, deflate"
Referer 
"http://www.example.com/index.php?id=22"
DNT 
"1"
Connection 
"keep-alive"
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests 
"1"

Comment: Chrome:

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie: bla
Host:www.example.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://www.example.com/index.php?id=22
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36

Comment: Okay, so i experimented a bit and setting the cookie from chrome did the trick in the developer tool.
But how do i set it in TYPO3 now?

Comment: That cookie did likely not magically appear by itself, but _was_ set by typo3. Some of your test browsers just did not want to accept that cookie ... due to browser settings or privacy add-ons.

Comment: Further exploring: Chrome in private sends 3 cookies and so does Firefox in non-private.